# Vite Production Error - Mixed Content The page at 'https://example.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite

currently i deploy a laravue app on heroku, and i got an error like this

> mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.herokuapp.com/' was loaded
> over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet
> 'http://example.herokuapp.com/build/assets/app.55a1010a.css'. This
> request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

the problem caused by vite production importing assets file via http not https.
and this is how i import my assets file how to fix this problem?

```
    @vite(['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/css/app.css'])
```

Comment: And what URL does .env file has? Change to https in the .env file too if you're using https.

Comment: i add env key APP_URL = `https://example.herokuapp.com/` and nothing happend

Comment: Run commands ``php artisan config:clear`` and ``npm run build``

Answer (score 0):

S1. Open .htaccess file and add the following line Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"

S2. remove these lines from your htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1
```

Please note that 443 port number is used for HTTPS requests.

Answer (score 0):

As you are deploying to Heroku, you are probably behind a proxy.
So you have to set Trusted Proxies. (See doc at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies)

You can open the file /app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php and then enable all ip if you don't know the proxy IP.

```
/**
* The trusted proxies for this application.
*
* @var array<int, string>|string|null
*/
protected $proxies = '*';
```